# Trying to find my posts

Tags: support, searching

I am trying to find all of my posts whether responded to or not.

I tried a search for `user:fixit7` but it found nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

User nickname is changeable and not necessarily unique, you need to use the unique numerical code associated to a user. So try `user:573838`. Alternatively, for self-posts, you can also use `user:me`.

Also in order to find your questions with an answer you may use `answers:1` (in general `answers:n` for questions with at least *n* answers). So simply search with `user:me answers:1`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could [just go to your user page](https://askubuntu.com/users/573838/fixit7) and see all your questions, answers, comments, etc. rather than using the system search tool which is fickle.  (But it does much the same as the search functions)